# Woocommerce order export API separate rows for each item for the same order Python

Tags: python, json, api, csv, woocommerce

I have the following code in Python. It gets json data from an API from woocommerce and then makes a csv file which i want so i can automate things. My problem is that the csv file that i get has in the same row under one column all the items purchased for the order. What i want is to have 1 row for each item with all the other columns remain the same for each order.

```
import requests
from woocommerce import API
import pandas as pd
import json
import pandas
import csv
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import flatten_json



wcapi = API(
    url="https://www.fempharm.gr",
    consumer_key="****************",
    consumer_secret="**************",
    wp_api=True,
    version="wc/v3"
)




data=wcapi.get("orders").json()

pandas.json_normalize(data)

with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)

df=pandas.read_json("C:\\Users\\John\\OneDrive - ΠΑΛΙΝ\\python projects\\data.json")
df.to_csv(r"C:\\Users\\John\\OneDrive - ΠΑΛΙΝ\\python projects\\data.csv")
df.to_excel(r"C:\\Users\\John\\OneDrive - ΠΑΛΙΝ\\python projects\\data.xlsx")
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I do not have all the code, but I do think I have a strategy, for those more code-knowledgeable than I am, as I hope you are.

Running this on my own data, I noticed that when the data frame is built by Pandas it does not create a series or every preexisting variable; which is, of course, your dilemma. For me, this means it clusters all the components of billing into the single series, "billing". Thus, billing comprises first_name, last_name, ... phone.

One possible solution I thought about is to extract each of those numerous-variables series separately and then normalize those. If the variables are separated as their own single file, rerunning the normalization or data-framing on each of them separately might extract each variable within as its own series. For example, if I could make the "billing" series its own file, then normalize it, I expect (hope) it would separate out each subcomponent.

**Does this *strategically* make sense?**

I used the following to successfully extracting the "billing" series into separate csv files:

```
import requests
from woocommerce import API
import pandas as pd
import json
import csv
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize



wcapi = API(
    url="https://yoursite.com",
    consumer_key="ck_your_key",
    consumer_secret="cs_your_secret",
    version="wc/v3"
)



orders_p1 = wcapi.get("orders", params={"per_page": 100, "page": 1}).json()
orders_p2 = wcapi.get("orders", params={"per_page": 100, "page": 2}).json()
orders_p3 = wcapi.get("orders", params={"per_page": 100, "page": 3}).json()



pd.json_normalize(orders_p1)
with open('orders_p1.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(orders_p1, f)


df=pd.read_json(r"C:\Users\...\orders_p1.json")
df.to_csv(r"C:\Users\...\orders_p1.csv") 

pd.json_normalize(orders_p2)
with open('orders_p2.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(orders_p2, f)


df2=pd.read_json(r"C:\Users\...\orders_p2.json")
df2.to_csv(r"C:\Users\...\orders_p2.csv") 

pd.json_normalize(orders_p3)
with open('orders_p3.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(orders_p3, f)


df3=pd.read_json(r"C:\Users\...\orders_p3.json")
df3.to_csv(r"C:\Users\...\orders_p3.csv")
```

Comment: I am going to edit the code I initially shared, but it works to accomplish what I said it would accomplish, i.e., pulling the information out separately for further scrubbing in Excel.
TBH, I had reached a point where spending more time trying to figure it out with Python was taking more time than I knew it would take to clean in Excel, so I stopped using Python beyond where the code ends.